# Stop my React for loop from executing when component umounts

Tags: reactjs, state, use-effect

I'm trying to stop a for loop from running when my component unmounts.

The isolated example is as follows:

My widget is a printer. When the printer is open, it prints "hello world" 1M times. And when the printer is closed it stops.

My problem is that I can't get the printer to stop printing when its closed. When I close the printer, the for loop continues to run. I thought that I would be able to stop the printer from printing by updating `isOpen`. But when I close the printer, the isOpen variable, in the scope of the for loop seems to be stuck on `true`. How can I interrupt the for loop from running when this component dismounts?

I seem to have some fundamental misunderstanding about how react state and functions work together.

```js
const SelectionPrinter = (props: {isOpen: boolean}): JSX.Element => {


    useEffect(() => {
        runThePrinter()
    }, [props.isOpen])

    const runThePrinter = (isOpen: boolean) => {
        for (let x = 0; x < 1000000; x++) {
            if (isOpen) {
                print(isOpen)
            }  
        }
    }

    const print = (isOpen: boolean) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (isOpen) {
                console.log("hello world")
            } else {
                console.log("goodbye")
            }
        })
    }

    return (<div> Printer </div>)
export default SelectionPrinter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React component functions are just regular old functions. Your `runThePrinter` function is also just a regular old synchronous function, so a render cycle for your component will go something like this (obviously this has been simplified):

1. React sees a `<SelectionPrinter isOpen={true} />` component somewhere (maybe your App component) and calls the `SelectionPrinter` function.
2. The `SelectionPrinter` function runs: it instantiates two functions, `runThePrinter` and `print`.
3. React calls your effect function, which in turn calls your `runThePrinter` function. This function loops for a million iterations and prints the `isOpen` state, or `true` a million times.

If you changed the prop `isOpen` during any of steps 1-3, it wouldn't matter - React will queue up a new render with the new props and state but it won't magically interupt a function that has already been called. Just like functions normally wouldn't have any special "watchers" or knowledge of anything beyond the variables they were called with, React component functions are just functions that are called with props and state. When props or state changes in these components, React calls their functions with the new reality, but it's not like it will interrupt a function to "inject" new props or state - it just calls the function.

I highly recommend [this article](https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/) by Dan Abramov, which is nominally about useEffect but sheds a lot of light on some common React misconceptions.

Comment: I got a little carried away with my explanation and didn't really answer your question fully - if you want to see the "latest" something, i.e. store a mutable value that is always current, check out [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). It's almost like opting out of the behavior I described above - React will give you the same ref object every render, and you can change it however you'd like. It won't trigger a re-render though.

Comment: Thanks for getting carried away! Your explanation was really helpful + I added the article to my TODO's. You rock.